# Deluge restarts downloading torrents everytime I log in

Tags: deluge

It asks for connecting to daemon and then it starts downloading files even if they are completed.

[image: asking for connection]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the files finished downloading they should start seeding. If you move them to another directory other than Deluge downloads location, Deluge will think they are gone and start downloading them again. I usually pause or remove torrents after they have finished downloading/seeding, which prevents Deluge from downloading them again.